# What kind of Encryption does YII2 and Laravel use?

Tags: laravel, yii2

I have an existing MYSQL database from a YII2 app. I need to use this database for my Laravel app however, I always get a `These credentials do not match our records.` during login in my laravel app. Do YII2 and Laravel has different Encryption method?

Comment: U can find info about password creation and verification there ihttps://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/base/Security.php#L21 But the final implementation may be different in Yii2 application, so u need to check source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the encryption but the structure, thay are not compatible, build your new app in Laravel and the use an ETL like Penaho Data Integration or write your own migration code.

Passwords are encrypted in a one way(SHA-2 or MD5), so you can't get them back.